# Storing credentials in an encrypted file

Tags: c#, encryption, credentials, storing-information

I'm working on a couple of projects that need to store user credentials for third-party applications, such as Paypal, Facebook developer creds etc. I've read a few books about different kinds of coding, including ASP.NET, WPF, jQuery, and all have nice examples on how to access the preceding services with own secrets, and also all of them use the exact phrase *"in a real project you would store these in an encrypted file"*. None, however, give an example how to do so.
I have little (read: none) experience in encryption, but based on my understanding, I would need to encrypt a username and a password using some sort of key (salt?) and save them in a file. I would also want to be able to use these credentials on my apps so I would need to store the key (salt?) in my code.
**Now my question is:** How is it safer to store the decryption key, which is still plain text, in the program code, than the actual credentials?
Wouldn't the malicious user be able to decrypt my password-file as soon as he gets the key?
--EDIT--
I really mean my own credentials I need to store to log in to third party applications, not credentials of my users. For example I need to identify my self and/or my app to Google, so that users can log in to my app using their own Google account.
--EDIT 2--
To clarify, this is what I'm talking about. This screenshot is from asp.net PayPal tutorial:
[image]
Any quick pointers on good practises here?

Comment: The two 3rd party applications you listed (Facebook and Paypal) explicitly ***forbid*** you from collecting credentials. You need to direct the user to the OAuth login page for their API and save the token it gives you when they log in.

Comment: I'm not talking about USER credentials, I'm talking about my own. I need to identify myself to PayPal so the money comes to me etc.. I need a whole lot of services that expect me to log in to use the services I pay for. I suppose that my web app should be able to do this without me punching in the username every time a user logs in.

Comment: If you are working on *a real product* I recommend that don't use standard encryption methods. Because, any malicious user wants to decrypt these file contents. So, in my case I'm using my own encryption algorithm. It doesn't matter that who; *hacker, attacker, malicious user, or etc* if knows the `key` (which I'm encrypting the my message using it) he/she **will never can find** the original message.
Shortly, I recommend that use your own encryption algorithm. (Don't trust any other algorithm. Coz, they're open source...)

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski Rolling your own encryption (AKA "security by obscurity") is an extremely dangerous advise. A sufficiently motivated hacker will hack your algorithm much faster than he would hack a key to a well-known, widely tested encryption system.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski I don't think you are being sarcastic, that is absolutely horrible advice. Please read the security.stackexcange.com question [Why shouldn't we roll our own?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own/18198)

Comment: @Sami Once again, per your update. Google does not require your credentials to do that either. It requires the ClientID and ClientSecret of your app (Which I guess you could call "your credentials").

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain Correct. And if these "secrets" are the ones that are used to point the direction of the money flow, wouldn't I want to keep them safe? Someone might replace them with their own and point the flow elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. But I think this method is safe again.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski And that is the problem. You ***think*** it is safe, but you don't ***know*** it is safe. It is very easy to write a cryptograpic system you can't break. It is very hard to write a cryptograpic system other people who do this every day for a living can't break. Please actually go and read the link I posted, you are putting your self at a risk you don't realaize.

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski why don't you answer the question, so it can be properly voted?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes, I think you're correct. And of course, I'm using my algorithm in my own system. And I didn't suggest anybody that *use my encryption algo*. And of course this is not safe for other people. I mean that *if it's your own system, just use your method*. That's it. 
I visited link you posted.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood the part about storing encrypted password<sup>*</sup> + salt: this is done when your system needs to validate someone else's credentials. In this situation storing password hash and the salt is more secure than storing the credentials, encrypted or not, because an attacker would have no way of getting the password back, even if he manages to get his hands on both the hash and the salt.

Storing decryption key in plain text is never a good option, because an attacker would get your users' passwords as soon as he gets access to the key.

There is no good solution to persisting your own credentials, encrypted or not. Your component that talks to 3-rd party services should use developer APIs from these providers. For example, PayPal [provides two sets of APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/) which you can use to access your account without having to store your password.

If you need to store a small amount of secret information in an encrypted form, use registry APIs to store the data in a key known to your application, and accessible from the user running your server-side component. This secret would be safe, as long as hackers do not hack the password for the account under which your service is running.

<sup>*</sup> Technically, password is not encrypted, it's hashed, i.e. there is no reliable way to turn the result of conversion back to the original value.

Answer (score 1):

Your suspicions are correct. If the user has access to the key they can just go and decrypt the username and passwords themselves.

The two options you have are

1. Make it difficult enough to get the password that the reword of getting the password is not worth the effort to find it. This approach is done via things like Code Obfuscateors, I would not recommend this to someone starting out. Its not easy to get it right and it only takes one person who things it is "worth the effort" for it to break.
2. Don't give the user the information ever. Instead of storing the usernames and passwords in the program have your program call out to a server you own, then that server is what makes the request using the credentials. This approach is the more reliable one and is "unbreakable" (as long as your server is secure) but costs more because you now need to keep a server up and running that can handle the load of your entire userbase.